# RecyclerView heavy lag with large list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am facing a heavy scroll lag on recyclerview when there are more than 50 items in the adapter. The fragment is skipping frames and the UI/UX is heavily affected. I am populating the list dynamically from the web as lazy loading.

[See the problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fufvCvaosROFmjoK1lNw7DfFN1wyjZe3/view?usp=sharing)

I have the following configuration of the recyclerview:

```
    myRecyclerView=getActivity().findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);
    myListAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);
    myListAdapter=new myListAdapter(myRecyclerView,getContext(),R.id.webMRFrame);
    myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    myRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);

    myRecyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(200);
    myRecyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    myRecyclerView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
    myRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myListAdapter);
```

RecyclerView layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/myFrameLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.bittentech.hindinews.Fragments.HomeFragment">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/mySwipeRefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/myNestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/myProgress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/myRecyclerView" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>



</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My Viewholder item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/myCardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_8x"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_8x"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/myImage"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/myTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_8x"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:includeFontPadding="false"
                    android:text="Sample Title"
                    android:textColor="@color/defaultContentColor"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_4x"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mySource"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_8x"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/myDate"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_12x" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <View
        android:layout_below="@id/myCardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

when you put the Recyclerview inside NestedScrollView the OnBindViewHolder method of the RecyclerAdapter call for each item and bind all the elements at once, which is an expensive task. So if you don't need the functionality of NestedScrollView, then remove it and use RecyclerView as the direct child of SwipeRefreshLayout.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
```

to your RecyclerView in XML file

Answer (score 0):

remove these lines:

```
myRecyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(200);
myRecyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
myRecyclerView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
```